# How to Download PDF in Edge using Selenium Python when Right Click is disabled?

Tags: python, selenium, pdf, microsoft-edge

http://nyshistoricnewspapers.org/lccn/np00030001/2010-02-22/ed-1/seq-1.pdf

If you visit this link in Edge browser, you will notice that there is absolutely no method to download this page using selenium webdriver. Due to following reasons:

- F12 or developer option does not provide any information
- Right Click in the header area is completely disabled.
- In the body area, Right Click to get inspect element is disabled or do not show

These issues are not present when using Chrome but with Edge browser only. I am restricted/limited to use Edge only at this time hence need help specific to Edge browser only.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't have a straight forward approach but You can try [PDFKit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit/0.4.1)

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf')
```

Comment: What has this answer to do with the question? Considering the question is *How to Download PDF in Edge using Selenium Python*, that is...

Comment: That was my bad, I overlooked it. Updated the answer with a python equivalent